# How to receive content of a page after submitting a form in perl?

Tags: perl

I've written a perl program for checking correct password in a form.
My algorithm is to fetch content of the login page before submitting form
and compare it with content of the login page after submitting form.
when I hit manually wrong password in that page the content of page changes
but in my script it is always equal.
I hope you understand what I want to do .
Here is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use WWW::Mechanize;
print "Usage : perl script.pl username passwordlist-path\n";
$username = $ARGV[0];
$password = $ARGV[1];
open(password , $password);
@passworddata = <password>;
close(password);
# print @passworddata;

$mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$url = "http://www.mysite.com/loginpage";
$mech ->get($url);
$u1 = $mech->content;
$mech->submit_form(
    form_number => 1,
    fields      => { 'userfield' => $username,
             'passfield' => @passworddate[0] },
    button      =>   'Submitfield'
        );
$u2 = $mech->content;

if ($u2 eq $u1) { print "Not Cracked\n"; }
else { print "Cracked\n"; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `$u1` and `$u2` are getting same date. `$u2` should be the submitted form's response.

```
$resp = $mech->submit_form

$u2 = $resp->content();
```

Comment: @user3475264 Try with `$resp->decoded_content();` But before anything, print the two `$u1`, `$u2` on a file and the do a file compare first.

Comment: Still it gives the same data !