# How to get content of a page after submitting form with WWW::Mechanize?

Tags: perl

I have a web page which is consist of a log in form . When I submit the form with WWW::Mechanize module in perl , The content of my page changes because username / password is wrong . I want to catch the content of the page after submitting form . I tried to use this :

```
$mech->content;
```

But that's not what I need.

This is a piece of my code :

```
$fields = {
    'usr' => $username,
    'passwd' => $password[0]  
};
$url = "http://blahblah.com/login/index.aspx?id=1";
$mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get($url);
$mech->submit_form(
    form_number=> 1,
    fields => $fields,
    button => 'button'
)
$mech->content;
```

Also see : [How to receive content of a page after submitting a form in perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728533/how-to-receive-content-of-a-page-after-submitting-a-form-in-perl?rq=1)

Comment: $mech->response->content ?

Comment: It works but the format of data is something like this : GsW,[Šá)ÆiæUEQ*anó_üA_êŒ¾±½¾ÂPßï*f‘Ö .

Comment: You are missing a semicolon at the end of ->submit_form()
Also: "use strict; use warnings;" in every perl script unless you have a reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

the following code works for me

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/ say /;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $username = '';
my $password = '';

my $fields = {
    usr    => $username,
    passwd => $password,
};

my $url  = "http://localhost:3000/login";
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

$mech->get($url);
$mech->submit_form(
    form_number => 1,
    fields      => $fields,
    button      => 'button'
);

say $mech->content;
```

Comment: Also I can fetch data with "content" but it is same as before submitting form . Although when I manually check the page , the content changes ! so the content befor submitting and after submitting must not be same !

Comment: Perhaps the website you are working with is using javascript. WWW::Mechanize does not support JS. (https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::FAQ#JavaScript)

It is really hard to tell without further information about the webpage you are requesting.

Comment: Yes it is javascritpt